# Nagios / snmp - client side requirement?

Tags: nagios, emc

I have an EMC NX4 that Im trying to monitor via Nagios. The command being sent is

```
check_snmp -H<server> -P1 -Cpublic -oDISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance -r Timeticks
```

What I get back is

```
SNMP problem - No data received from host
CMD: /usr/bin/snmpget -t 1 -r 5 -m ALL -v 1 [authpriv] <server>:161  DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance
```

This works on my other EMC device so there is something that needs to be installed on the NX4. What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your server isn't getting an SNMP response from the NX4. There's not a lot of detail here, but here's how I would diagnose this:

- Make sure you have network connection (ping)
- One the NX4, make sure SNMP is turned on, and verify community strings
- Use a tool like *snmpwalk* to make sure you can get a response to an SNMP query
- Finally, check the MIB to make sure you've got the correct variable

Some devices will make a log entry for invalid SNMP requests (bad OID or community) - that may be useful as well for diagnosis.